# Filter dataframe based on +- x hours around a time of observation

Tags: r, dataframe, time, filtering, spatial

I have an ascii file read as a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
points <- data.frame(c(5.177, 6.57, 20.97, -1.18),
                       c(52.1, 46.49, 52.4, 60.14),
                       c("08:30:12", "09:45:20", "11:33:22", "14:12:43")
                       )

names(points) <- c('lon', 'lat', 'Time')
```

The real dataset has about 150000 rows and the time column is class "character".

Now, what I want to do is to filter based on a time period around a known observation. Let's say this observation happened at 11:00:00 (All times are in UTC), and I want to know which measurements fall within a 3hr period of this known observation.

So I need to filter out the values that do not fall within 1.5 hours +- of 11:00:00.

In the end I want to then select the nearest observation in space, which works already. But I can't find out how to select based on this time constraint. The final function look something like this:

```
nearestPixel <- function(matrix, station, time) {
  # filter based on time (3 hours around time of measurement)
  ## TODO ##

  # select just lat/lon from both datasets
  surfset <- SpatialPoints(surfmatrix[, 1:2])
  stationset <- SpatialPoints(station[, 2:3])

  # calculate closest point in distance
  nearest <- apply(gDistance(surfset, stationset, byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)

}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me, whether 1. all times are from the same date and 2. what should happen, if the 1.5 h overlap falls outside daily limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below code in place of #todo assuming all time is from the same date. I have kept Hour_Difference column in data just for your reference, you can deselect it if not required

```
library(lubridate)
points$Time<- hms(points$Time) # changing it to time

t1<-hms("11:00:00") #reference time as mentioned by you

points %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(Hour_Difference=hour(t1-Time)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(abs(Hour_Difference)<3) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Hour_Difference)
```

output:

```
    lon   lat        Time Hour_Difference
1  6.57 46.49  9H 45M 20S               2
2 20.97 52.40 11H 33M 22S               0
```

Or if you want one liner:

```
points %>% 
  dplyr::filter(abs(lubridate::hour(t1-Time))<3)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. How would I go about deselecting this so it won't get added to my dataframe?

Comment: @B.Quaink added in the answer and as my suggestion suitably answers your question, click the tick mark to accept it as the chosen answer.